# What factors can make the same LaTeX file render differently on different systems?

Tags: compiling

Last night, om my home PC, I finally managed to cut the length of a document to the required maximum of 10 pages. This morning, when I opened the same file (synced via dropbox) on my work PC and compile it again (using pdflatex, just like at home), I suddenly have some text on the 11th page. How is this possible?

Both PCs run on Windows 10 with the latest version of MikTeX installed. I am using biblatex and biber for the bibliography.

I might add that one (maybe the only) thing that I can spot rendering differently is an entry in the bibliography. I know this because I remember shortening the publisher name of that bib-entry to make it use only one line and it did. But now it has gone back to two lines (despite the shorter publisher).

The purpose of this question is not so much to solve this particular problem of mine but to better understand the factors that make this possible. Because, if I'm not mistaken, it should not happen under normal circumstances.

Comment: You may think, that both installations of MiKTeX are same. But it would be better to really compare the versions of LaTeX, the classes and the packages, e.g., using `\listfiles`. Even different font versions could result in different paragraph and page break.

Comment: There is a urban legend that someone republish a font with slightly different parameters and it destroy someone else's whole book.